# Invalid Update When adding Rows to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I'm trying to add rows to a table view when a user taps a row, to create an expandable section, however the extra rows aren't being counted before Xcode tries to add them in and as such causes this error (I think). Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
// sectionExpanded is set to false in viewDidLoad. It is set to true when
// the user taps on the expandable section (section 0 in this case)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 && sectionExpanded {
        return 5
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

// This should recount the rows, add the new ones to a temporary array and then add
// them to the table causing the section to 'expand'.

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = menu[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MenuCell
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        var rows: Int
        var tmpArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        sectionExpanded = !sectionExpanded
        rows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)

        for i in 1...rows {
            var tmpIndexPath: NSIndexPath
            tmpIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)

            tmpArray.addObject(tmpIndexPath)
        }

        if !sectionExpanded {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        } else {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        }
    } else {
        delegate?.rightItemSelected(selectedItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is telling you that you are trying to insert 1 new row, but numberofrows should be 5, before was 1 and you are trying to insert 1 new row, thats 2. Theres your problem.

```
rows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) //this returns 1
for i in 1...rows { //
    var tmpIndexPath: NSIndexPath
    tmpIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)

    tmpArray.addObject(tmpIndexPath)//this will contain only 1 object, because the loop will run only for 1 cycle
}
```

#### EDIT

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedItem = menu[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MenuCell
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        var rows: Int
        var tmpArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        sectionExpanded = !sectionExpanded
        rows = 1
        if sectionExpanded {
            rows = 5
        }

        for i in 1...rows {
            var tmpIndexPath: NSIndexPath
            tmpIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)

            tmpArray.addObject(tmpIndexPath)
        }

        if !sectionExpanded {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        } else {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        }
    } else {
        delegate?.rightItemSelected(selectedItem)
    }
}
```

Since you know number of rows will be always 5 or 1, you can try something like this. However, this is not a standard approach, I would suggest to alter your datasource array.
Here is some example how to do it: http://www.nsprogrammer.com/2013/07/updating-uitableview-with-dynamic-data.html its for Objective-C but you will get the gist of it.

Comment: Shouldn't it get updated when I change the number or rows in section though? Is there any way to ensure that it is updated?

Comment: @ChrisByatt i updated my answer with possible solutions for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try modifying the data source and then reload the table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths...` and the like between a `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. The tableView will *collect* all the changes after `beginUpdates()` and then will apply them coherently after `endUpdates()`. So try something like:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
if !sectionExpanded {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        } else {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(tmpArray, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
        }
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Remember that after the call to `endUpdates()` the number of sections and rows must be consistent with your model.

Since I don't know about your model, here's a simple example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sectionExpanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != sectionExpanded {

                let expIndexes = map(0..<model.count) { r in
                    NSIndexPath(forRow: r, inSection: 0)
                }

                // Here we start the updates
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                switch sectionExpanded {
                case false:
                    // Collapsing
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(expIndexes, withRowAnimation: .Top)
                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Top)
                default:
                    // Expanding
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Top)
                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(expIndexes, withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
                }
                // Updates ended
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }

    let model = ["foo", "bar", "zoo"]

    //MARK: UITableView DataSource

    struct TableConstants {
        static let sectionCellIdentifier = "SectionCell"
        static let expandedCellIdentifier = "ExpandedCell"
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionExpanded ? model.count : 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch sectionExpanded {
        case false:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
                TableConstants.sectionCellIdentifier,
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "The Section Collapsed Cell"
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
                TableConstants.expandedCellIdentifier,
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(model[indexPath.row])"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Index: \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        sectionExpanded = !sectionExpanded
    }
}
```

Note that I moved the table updates to the `sectionExpanded` *observer*.

Comment: Sadly no joy, it's still only returning 1 on rows = ..etc

Answer (score 0):

You already have 1 row in `section = 0`, and trying to insert 5 new rows. You can only add 4 rows more to map with `numberOfRowsInsection`.

Try following code:

```
    sectionExpanded = !sectionExpanded
    rows = self.numberOfRowsInSection(0)-1

    for i in 1...rows {
        var tmpIndexPath: NSIndexPath
        tmpIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)

        tmpArray.addObject(tmpIndexPath)
    }
```

Comment: Thats not true, he is not trying to insert 5 new rows, but it clearly says he is inserting 1. Check my answer to understand what his code is doing

Comment: sectionExpanded = !sectionExpanded

This changes the game!